# Loading different Background images in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

My requirement is , i have 2 background images (img1 nad img2) and while loading page img1 should load and on top of this image one button should create and click on the button , the background image img1 should disapper and img2 has to appear. I want to use for this scenario using HTML5.

Can anyone suggest the code , how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this code will automatically load when the page loads. So you donot need to write any JS code for the `onload=""` event. This way, the background will be set on load itself.

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

CSS code for this element will be.

```
#div {
  background-image: url('image/url/file1.png');
}
```

And then on the click, use this button and an event handler for that button.

```
<button onclick="changeimage()">Click Me</button>
```

For function, use this code which will replace the current image's src attribute

```
function changeimage() {
    document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundImage = "url('link/to/file2.png')";
}
```

This way the first image will load on start. And when a click event will occur on the button. The src will be changed to the second image, and it will be replaced with the second one. HTML5 for elements and pure JS for image replacement! :)

Comment: image should be as background image .? if i given <img src='' /> will display the image as background image?

Comment: No, then you'll need jQuery..something like this..`.style.backgroundImage = "";` and for the image, you'll use CSS properties for `background-image: `

Comment: function changeimage() is not working means background is not changing while click on the button

Comment: Sorry, change the value of the backgroundImage related to the one that I have provided you with now..:)